# CDATA not supporting to read data from XMLList

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

**XML :**

```
  <catering>
        <contents>
        <![CDATA[
            <title>UPCOMING EVENTS</title>
            <info _title = "<font size='14' color='#ffffff'>title1</font" image="null"></info>
            <info _title = "title2" image="images/events/slide1.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title3 " image="images/events/slide2.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title4" image="images/events/slide3.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title5" image="images/events/slide4.jpg"></info>
            ]]
        </contents>
    </catering>
```

**CODE**

```
 eventTitle = loadXMLC.events_1_Contents.contents.title;
 xmlList_1 = loadXMLC.events_1_Contents.contents.info;
 for(i = 0;i < xmlList_1.@_title.length(); i++)
 {
    events_0_info.push(xmlList_1.@_title[i]);
    img_ary0.push(xmlList_1.@image[i]);

 }
```

Without `CDATA` I can able to read the XML. What do I needs to do read the data with CDATA?

I want to use html tag for each attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick exemple :

```
var data : XML = <catering>
    <contents>
        <![CDATA[
        <title>UPCOMING EVENTS</title>
        <info _title = "title2" image="images/events/slide1.jpg"></info>
        <info _title = "title3 " image="images/events/slide2.jpg"></info>
        <info _title = "title4" image="images/events/slide3.jpg"></info>
        <info _title = "title5" image="images/events/slide4.jpg"></info>
        ]]>
        </contents>
    </catering>;
```

The nodes between CDATA tag are seen as text (a block of text). You have to convert this text into a valid XML in order to access data.

```
trace(XML(data.contents.children()).nodeKind());//text
var contents : XMLList = XML("<c>"+data.contents.toString()+"</c>").children();
trace(contents.toXMLString());
```

I removed this line from your sample :

```
<info _title = "<font size='14' color='#ffffff'>title1</font" image="null"></info>
```

Flash was unable to convert this line into XML...

Comment: Is I can't able to access with html tags?

Comment: if i understand your question : i don't think that you can put your html tags inside a tag attribute in XML...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of a typo where you're closing the `CDATA` tag. Try adding `>` at the end like so:

```
<catering>
    <contents>
        <![CDATA[
            <title>UPCOMING EVENTS</title>
            <info _title = "<font size='14' color='#ffffff'>title1</font" image="null"></info>
            <info _title = "title2" image="images/events/slide1.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title3 " image="images/events/slide2.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title4" image="images/events/slide3.jpg"></info>
            <info _title = "title5" image="images/events/slide4.jpg"></info>
        ]]>
    </contents>
</catering>
```

and you'll be good to go.

**EDIT**

As @OXMO456 mentions. Flash parsing won't go past the first `_title` attribute. I think the way you're using the xml attributes is a bad practice. In essence attributes contain information about the element, not the content of the element itself.

Maybe you should try adjusting the xml structure a bit and try parsing that. Maybe something like this could work:

```
<title>UPCOMING EVENTS</title>
<info>
    <title size="14" color="#ffffff">title1</title>
</info>
<info>
    <title>title2</title>
    <image>images/events/slide2.jpg</image>
</info>
<info>
    <title>title3</title>
    <image>images/events/slide3.jpg</image>
</info>
<info>
    <title>title4</title>
    <image>images/events/slide4.jpg</image>
</info>
```

Comment: I adjusted my answer a bit. I didn't really tested the parsing, my bad.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean with `HTML tags`. Your <info> elements don't contain any.